# C# SMO scripting constraints order

Tags: c#, smo

I'm using SMO to generate a script of my tables and database.

Here is my code for the scripter options:

```
        Scripter CreateScrp = new Scripter(srv);
        CreateScrp.Options.ScriptDrops = false; // Script drop statements
        CreateScrp.Options.WithDependencies = true; // Walk dependencies
        CreateScrp.Options.DriAllConstraints = true;   // to include referential constraints in the script
        CreateScrp.Options.Triggers = true; // Script triggers
        CreateScrp.Options.NoCollation = false; // Use default collation       
        CreateScrp.Options.ExtendedProperties = true; // Script Extended Properties
        CreateScrp.Options.SchemaQualify = true; // Qualify objects with schema names
        CreateScrp.Options.ScriptSchema = true; // Script schema
        CreateScrp.Options.IncludeDatabaseContext = true;
        CreateScrp.Options.EnforceScriptingOptions = true;
        CreateScrp.ScriptingProgress += CreateScrp_ScriptingProgress;
```

But when I execute the query, the constraints (here foreign key) have errors because the table which the foreign key comes from has not been created yet.
In my generated script, MaterialActual table is created before MaterialUse.

SQL Server error:
Msg 1767, Level 16, State 0, Line 561
Foreign key 'FK_MaterialActual_MaterialUse' references invalid table 'dbo.MaterialUse'.

The issue is coming from the order of tables creation.
Are there any options in the scripter for that?

Regards

Comment: You could [walk the dependencies yourself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.dependencywalker.aspx) to script them in order. Also, if you're not married to SMO, consider using [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) to import your database as a [database project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh864423), as DACPAC deployment solves the problem of dependencies itself.

Comment: I'm not allowed to install those kinds of tools on my work computer. I will try with the dependency walker. Thx ;)

Comment: Convince everyone at work that database projects are awesome, so SSDT gets installed on every work computer by the Powers that Be -- problem solved. Admittedly, that's a bit out of scope for this question... (Note that if you have Visual Studio, you likely already have (some version of) database project support, just not the most awesome version.)

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2015. I have to create a ticket for the installation and if it's not in the approved software catalog it will be rejected ^^ I don't have a word to say sadly.

Comment: File -> New -> Project, Installed -> Templates -> SQL Server -> SQL Server Database Project. With any luck it's already there. (And yes, you do have a word to say, at least in any company that values productivity -- but that's a completely different discussion for a completely different site.)

Comment: Indeed VS2015 have it ^^ Thx i will investigate this

Comment: Database projects are great. As a side-effect your DB structure can be under source control too!